# How to set the Application Folder on installation

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-installer, installation

I need to copy some files to the Application folder when installing with an msi. I was looking at using a launch condition to establish if the folder exists but I need to continue and install in an alternative folder if FALSE.

can I programatically set the Application Folder at installation

Comment: What is the point of using an alternate folder if the expected one doesn't exist?  Make alternate = expected and you're home free.

Comment: The 3rd party application that my plugin installs to will be in either of 2 locations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use file search or a custom action which checks whether one of the folders exists. Then you use mutually exclusive conditions on two custom actions, which will set the value of a property, `PLUGINDIR`. Then you use this property as the target directory for plugin files.

You have to do it before MSI goes to [`InstallInitialize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369505.aspx) action.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should always let the user descide what the application folder should be.

Second: depending on the tool you use for creating the msi it must be possible to read the selected installation folder and copy file to it. e.g. When you use a Visual Studio Setup Project you can use [TARGETDIR] as a property in the File System view. With that you can ouput files in your solution to that folder.

Comment: It's not possible to let the user decide, because the deployment must go in an existing application folder. I need to be able to dynamically set this folder depending where the existing application is deployed

Comment: I can think of a variety of situations that would be an exception to allowing the user that choice.